# Jquery dialog textboxes value binding is not working

Tags: jquery, jsf

i am not able to get textbox value from jquery dialog, below is my code

```
$("#printbutton").click(function() {
        $("#print").dialog("open");
    });

$("#print").dialog({
        autoOpen : false,
        modal : true,
        resizable : false,
        draggable : false,
        show : {
            effect : "fade"
        },
        hide : {
            effect : "fade"
        },
        open: function (type, data) {
            $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
        }
    });
```

JSF Code

```
<h:form> 
  <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="print">
    <h:inputText value="#{bean.text1}" id="text1"/>
    <h:inputText value="#{bean.text2}" id="text2"/>
    <h:inputText value="#{bean.text3}" id="text3"/>
    <h:commandButton action="#{bean.button} id="printbutton">
  </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

Java Code

```
String text1;
String text2;
String text3;

public String getText1() {
    return text1;
}

public void setText1(String text1) {
    this.text1 = text1;
}

public String getText2() {
    return text2;
}

public void setText2(String text2) {
    this.text2 = text2;
}

public String getText3() {
    return text3;
}

public void setText3(String text3) {
    this.text3 = text3;
}

public void button(){
    System.out.println(text1);
    System.out.println(text2);
    System.out.println(text3);
}
```

I am able to call the button method from jsf page.
But I am getting null values for all the three textboxes in my java code. please help me.

Comment: What do you mean by getting `null` values for your textboxes? What's the scope of your managed bean? How can we reproduce your current problem?

Comment: Did you look at stdout(console)? Have you see there any text from your texboxes?

Comment: I am using session scope to get the textbox values. But i am getting null values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

```
$("#printbutton").click(function() {
        $("#print").dialog("open");
    });
```

Change your button like this:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{bean.button} 
                 id="printbutton"
                 oncomplete="$('#print').dialog('open');"
/>
```

(I suppose jquery is able to find all related ids)